# speed: nginx on windows with php fastcgi hosting laravel

Tags: windows, nginx, php, apache-2.4

I'm trying to host a laravel app on a windows machine and I am trying to find out whether I should use WAMP or WNMP for best speed. Right now I have nginx and php fastcgi running in service wrappers. I have been searching and found threads about nginx having the best scalability due to its event driven nature but I have not been able to figure what happens when the requests start piling up on the php fastcgi process.

the limited on 1024 concurrent connections of the worker of nginx is fine. My only concern is the php behind the windows nginx.

I have yet to find a discussion about the way the php fastcgi server acts with multiple requests (ie. threads, event driven noblocking...etc.)

I have read on some sites about running apache to handle dynamic content while nginx handles all the static content. I'm wondering if that means the best windows config for laravel is for apache to run as a fastcgi (I'm not even sure if that is possible) with mod_php behind an nginx

Thanks in advance to anyone who can clear up my confusion :)

The linked post does contain a discussion of WAMP as a stack vs Windows with each component installed separately, but I'm curious about WEMP/WNMP) vs WAMP

-Chris

Comment: The answer is _neither_. See the linked question.

Comment: I;m a little embarrassed to admit I can't find the question of which this is a duplicate. Can you point me in the direction to it?